# How can I play music continue in other iOS app when I record audio complete in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, audio-recording

How can I play music continue in other `iOS` app when I record audio completely in my app?

Comment: Sorry, this question is too difficult to understand.

Comment: elaborate your question

Comment: Don't know why many close this !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your audio session to inactive with the flag to notify others set as well, then the other app should restart.  For iOS5 with AVAudioSession you could do this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

Note that this has been deprecated in iOS6 and replaced with:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersonDeactivation error:nil];
```

There will be a C interface for this as well.